# How to get current Date

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, rtc

How to get Current date, month and year. I have used RTC, NTPClient, but it didn't work. This gives default output of 1970. What can I do for fixing it.

```cpp
time_t now = time(nullptr);
struct tm* newtime = localtime(&now);
String tmpNow = "";
tmpNow += String(newtime->tm_year + 1900);
tmpNow += "-";
tmpNow += String(newtime->tm_mon + 1);
tmpNow += "-";
tmpNow += String(newtime->tm_mday);
tmpNow += " ";
```

Comment: I don't think that the Arduino knows what date it is. To use NTPClient you need to connect Arduino to internet somehow so the date can be downloaded from NTPServer.

Comment: It is already connected to internet

Comment: Then you probably have a bug somewhere. Post your code here so we can check what's wrong. Use "code" button to format it in readable way.

Comment: From what library you get the "localtime" function? I can't find it in any of the libraries you referenced above.

Answer (score 4):

An [example](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/NTPClient/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.ino) how to use NTPClient is available at the projects github

```cpp
#include <NTPClient.h>
// change next line to use with another board/shield
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//#include <WiFi.h> // for WiFi shield
//#include <WiFi101.h> // for WiFi 101 shield or MKR1000
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char *ssid     = "<SSID>";
const char *password = "<PASSWORD>";

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay ( 500 );
    Serial.print ( "." );
  }

  timeClient.begin();
}

void loop() {
  timeClient.update();

  Serial.println(timeClient.getFormattedTime());

  delay(1000);
}
```

Form what I found TimeRTC requires an external device called DS1307RTC to keep track of the time as shown in [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6wkvTG2Ofs) and with it we should be able to get the real time as seen in github [example](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/blob/master/examples/TimeRTC/TimeRTC.ino)

```cpp
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>  // a basic DS1307 library that returns time as a time_t

void setup()  {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // wait until Arduino Serial Monitor opens
  setSyncProvider(RTC.get);   // the function to get the time from the RTC
  if(timeStatus()!= timeSet) 
     Serial.println("Unable to sync with the RTC");
  else
     Serial.println("RTC has set the system time");      
}

void loop()
{
  if (timeStatus() == timeSet) {
    digitalClockDisplay();
  } else {
    Serial.println("The time has not been set.  Please run the Time");
    Serial.println("TimeRTCSet example, or DS1307RTC SetTime example.");
    Serial.println();
    delay(4000);
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void digitalClockDisplay(){
  // digital clock display of the time
  Serial.print(hour());
  printDigits(minute());
  printDigits(second());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(day());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(month());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(year()); 
  Serial.println(); 
}

void printDigits(int digits){
  // utility function for digital clock display: prints preceding colon and leading 0
  Serial.print(":");
  if(digits < 10)
    Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(digits);
}
```

If what I understand from your code you are actually not using any RTP or NTP. You are only creating a Time object with no values and you read it default values.

Check some more examples [here](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/tree/master/examples)

Comment: using RTC it gives output like -jan 8 2013 . How to get current date and year

Comment: @ShivaniDongre Are you 100% sure that the DS1307RTC has correct date setup? It depends on it's battery to keep date updated. If at any point the battery was removed date is reset to default value, and then inserting a new battery makes it count time from January first.